# IdentityServer4 checkPasswordAsync Change Default Error Message (login)

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, identity

I am using IdentityServer4. I want to change the fixed warning messages while logging in. How can I do that.

```
   public async Task ValidateAsync(ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext context)
        {
            var existUser = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(context.UserName);
            if (existUser == null) return;
            var passwordCheck = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(existUser, context.Password);
            if (passwordCheck == false) return;

            context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(existUser.Id.ToString(), OidcConstants.AuthenticationMethods.Password);
   
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using default template AspNetCore.Identity with IdentityServer4.

You need to override the messages on IdentityErrorDescriber.

```
public class CustomIdentityErrorDescriber : IdentityErrorDescriber
{
    public override IdentityError DefaultError()
    {
        return new IdentityError
        {
            Code = nameof(DefaultError),
            Description = "Your custom message"
        };
    }
}
```

On startup add AddErrorDescriber on your AddIdentity:

```
  services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
     .AddErrorDescriber<CustomIdentityErrorDescriber>();
```

Update

It will break OIDC spec... but here we go.

add a CustomResourceOwnerPasswordValidator

```
public class CustomResourceOwnerPasswordValidator<TUser> : IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator
       where TUser : class
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<TUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<TUser> _userManager;
        private readonly ILogger<CustomResourceOwnerPasswordValidator<TUser>> _logger;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="CustomResourceOwnerPasswordValidator{TUser}"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userManager">The user manager.</param>
        /// <param name="signInManager">The sign in manager.</param>
        /// <param name="logger">The logger.</param>
        public CustomResourceOwnerPasswordValidator(
            UserManager<TUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<TUser> signInManager,
            ILogger<CustomResourceOwnerPasswordValidator<TUser>> logger)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Validates the resource owner password credential
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context">The context.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public virtual async Task ValidateAsync(ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext context)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(context.UserName);
            if (user != null)
            {
                var result = await _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, context.Password, true);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    var sub = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);

                    _logger.LogInformation("Credentials validated for username: {username}", context.UserName);

                    context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(sub, OidcConstants.AuthenticationMethods.Password);
                    return;
                }
                else if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("Authentication failed for username: {username}, reason: locked out", context.UserName);
                }
                else if (result.IsNotAllowed)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("Authentication failed for username: {username}, reason: not allowed", context.UserName);
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("Authentication failed for username: {username}, reason: invalid credentials", context.UserName);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("No user found matching username: {username}", context.UserName);
            }

            context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidGrant,"your custom message here");
        }
    }
```

On startup:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
.AddResourceOwnerValidator<CustomResourceOwnerPasswordValidator<User>>();//Must be last, but before AddDeveloperSigningCredential
```

Will return this :

```
"{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"your custom message here"}"
```

Comment: `​public override IdentityError DefaultError() => new IdentityError { Code = nameof(DefaultError), Description = "Bilinmeyen bir hata oluştu !" };
​`
@Alexrgs I did that. It works. The error I want to edit is checkpasswordasync error. The error is below when i want to edit

​`
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "invalid_username_or_password"
}
`

Comment: @EmreŞimşek that's an OIDC spec message, you should not change it. However you can change it [here] (https://damienbod.com/2017/04/14/asp-net-core-identityserver4-resource-owner-password-flow-with-custom-userrepository/) you find how to write your CustomResourceOwnerPasswordValidator